# Python summation

Tags: python, math, equation

I am a very new python user.
I am trying to calculate a summation series.

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM1iU.png)

I have a table with values (see below) for `a_(ij)` with `p = 10`.

```
data = [["a_{ij}", "j=0", "j=1", "j=2", "j=3"],
["i=1", 4.3, 8.3, 2.9, `1.3],
["i=2", 1.4, 4.7, 6,5, 3.2]]
```

---

```
a_(ij)  j = 0  j = 1  j = 2  j = 3
i = 1    4.3    8.3    2.9     1.3
i = 2    1.4    4.7    6.5     3.2
.
.
i = 20   8.34   2.13  7.93   6.322
```

Instead of writing a code separately for each value of y.

```
# For i = 1
y_1 = 4.3*10**0 + 8.3*10**1 + 2.9*10**2 + 1.3*10**3
```

Is there an easier way to save time?

Comment: Can you post more of the code so we know how the table is stored, etc?

Comment: What is `a_(ij)`, is it an array? How is your data for the table stored? If you have not been introduced to arrays/lists you should read about them and know that you can nest them inside each other.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: A_(ji) is just a heading for my table. The first row and column are heading for the table.

Comment: By the way your calculation example `y_1 = 4.3*10**4.3 + 8.3*10**8.3 + 2.9*10**2.9 + 1.3*10**1.3` indicates that you want to calculate `p` to the power of `a_(ij)`, instead of to the power of `j`, which is what the equation you posted indicates. Which exponent is the right one?

Comment: Thank you for @blhsing for pointing out my mistake.  It is to the power of `j`

Comment: @Duchess I see. I've updated my answer below to reflect your correction then.

Comment: @Duchess Also, the equation you posted indicates that the index of the summation starts from 1, not 0, but your calculation indicates that you want it to start from 0. Which lower bound is correct?

Comment: @blhsing, the lower bound is starting from zero.

Comment: @Duchess I see. The equation in the image is incorrect then.

Comment: @Duchess I just realized that `zip` and `starmap` are unnecessary and could be replaced with a simple `map`. I've edited my answer so that it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clean solution:

```
>>> a = [
...     [4.3, 8.3, 2.9, 1.3],
...     [1.4, 4.7, 6,5, 3.2]
... ]
>>> p = 10.0
>>> import operator
>>> [sum(map(operator.mul, i, map(p.__pow__, range(len(i))))) for i in a]
[1677.3, 37648.4]
```

Replace `zip` with `izip` and import `izip` from `itertools` if you're using python 2.7.

And here's the result of the manual calculation you posted for comparison:

```
>>> 4.3*10**0 + 8.3*10**1 + 2.9*10**2 + 1.3*10**3
1677.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Store a_(ij) as a matrix.  Either make it a 2D array, or use the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) library and make it a numpy matrix.

2D Array Example:

```
a = [[4.3, 8.3, 2.9, 1.3],
     [1.4, 4.7, 6.5, 3.2],
     # you've indicated more lines will go here
     [8.34, 2.13, 7.93, 6.322]]
```

If a is something that can be generated by a function, I would recommend generating your 2D array that way rather than manually entering values.

Then you can implement your formula as a function:

```
def y(i):
    p = 10
    total = 0
    for j in range(1,4):
        total += a[i][j] * p**j
    return total
```

Now you can get values of y for any value of i you like by calling the function e.g. `y(1)` will give the value of y for i=1.

You could also generate an array for y (if you are frequently reusing the same y value, your code will run faster if you keep it cached in an array instead of recalculating the y every time).

Comment: I tried your code but when I want the value of `y(1)`, the value that return back to me is wrong compare to manual calculation.

Comment: Check for off-by-one errors (python is 0-indexed, meaning if `a=[1,2,3,4]`, `a[0]` = 1, `a[1]` = 2, and so on.  Note that based on your summation of j from 1 to 3 shown in your image, you will only be using the values in the last 3 columns of a, which I thought is a little strange and is inconsistent with your sample calculation.  My suggestion is to have a as a 2D array and y as a function.  The exact implementation of that is up to you.